# Array Length in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this sort of questions have been answered before also . But I still am not able get completely over it .

Via a server call I am getting a list back. I am trying to get the count of the list by **length** property.

But it is always undefined.

```
        $http(request)
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response != "Failed!" && response != "FileAlreadyUploaded") {
                        $scope.pleaseWait = { "display": "none" };

                        console.log("Succeeds");

                        UploadDataServices.setInvalidRecordsCount(response.GroupMembershipInputList.length);
```

If I see in the browser console , I get to see the property.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What's in the `setInvalidRecordsCount` ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi .. I am setting the returned length in Angular service variable.

Comment: @Tushar I am not asking to figure out a way to return from an async call . I am just not understanding why length is undefined even though the array has items within it. So it is not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the response in one variable and check the variable value using console.log and if that variable has value try passing the variable instead of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys. It was mistake on my part only . It just happened there was another nested array object with just similar name .. GroupMembershipUploadInputList and that had it's length .